# Should I not use built-in tuple specific functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, magic-methods

When I look up the methods for the built-in collection type *tuple* [online](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_tuple.asp), it says that tuples have only two methods:`count()` and `index()`. However, whenever I try to look up pydoc for tuples:

```
python -m pydoc tuple
```

I get the following:

```
Help on class tuple in module builtins:

class tuple(object)
 |  tuple(iterable=(), /)
 |
 |  Built-in immutable sequence.
 |
 |  If no argument is given, the constructor returns an empty tuple.
 |  If iterable is specified the tuple is initialized from iterable's items.
 |
 |  If the argument is a tuple, the return value is the same object.
 |
 |  Built-in subclasses:
 |      asyncgen_hooks
 |      UnraisableHookArgs
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self+value.
 |
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      Return key in self.
 |
 |  __eq__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self==value.
 |
 |  __ge__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self>=value.
 |
 |  __getattribute__(self, name, /)
 |      Return getattr(self, name).
 |
 |  __getitem__(self, key, /)
 |      Return self[key].
 |
```

It goes on for a while. I noticed that if I want to add an element(s) to a tuple, then I have to create a new tuple.

```
a = ('hi', 'my')
b = (*a, 'name', 'is')
>>> b
('hi', 'my', 'name', 'is')
```

But the method **add**() does the same thing for me.

Are the methods that pop up in the pydocs the module specific methods that aren't intended to be used outside of the module? I suppose kinda like a weak form of encapsulation?

EDIT: Took out 'module' from the title. @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct. tuple is not a module.

Comment: I think w3schools (which is not a very good resource) means that there are two non-special methods. Dunder methods represent operators

Comment: Those are all "special methods", which are *hooks* for various syntactical constructs or built-in functions. E.g. `__len__` is used by `len(x)`, `__add__` is used by `x + y` etc. They are not meant to be called directly.

Comment: Also, this isn't a module...

Comment: Read the official documentation, not W3S: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right. change the title to reflect that

Comment: @deceze I couldn't find anywhere in the official documentation where it lays out tuple's methods. At least not like it does for lists [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Anyways, if W3S' information is correct, then what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. W3Schools is a very questionable source of information, as they're often wrong, misleading, or incomplete. Use the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) as your primary source of information.
2. Tuples implement the [*common sequence operations*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common). Everything that's defined as a "[sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)" supports certain operations, and `count` and `index` are two of those. The rest of the sequence operations aren't implemented as specific methods, but through operators. E.g., adding two sequences together:

   ```
   (1, 2) + (3, 4)
   ```

   This is implemented in the `tuple` class through the [`__add__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__). That's how all operators interact with values in Python: `a + b` gets translated into `a.__add__(b)`. This way, each object can customise what exactly it means to "add" it to another object. You should always use these abstract definitions using operators, not call specific `__add__` methods yourself.

   And yes, tuples are *immutable*, so you cannot extend an existing tuple, you can only add two tuples together into a new tuple.

Comment: Gotcha. I was confused at why the official documentation didn't lay out tuples methods, like lists do, but your answer makes sense. I didn't catch that tuples don't have any methods outside of the Common Sequence Operations. Thanks!

Comment: It does take a little bit of getting used to that Python likes to define things in terms of abstract notions like "sequences", "iterables" etc., and what "operations" those things support. If you expect documentation which lists methods of a class, that can feel a bit weird. But once you get used to this, it makes a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The methods pydoc mentions, start and end with a double underscore. These are used to implement operators, inbuilt methods etc. And are supposed to be rarely called.

[From the Python PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> [**Descriptive: Naming Styles**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles)
>
> - *double_leading_and_trailing_underscore*_: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. **init**, **import** or **file**. Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

And w3schools isn't a good reference, always check the Python docs. For example - [Tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html)